# Convert Entire JDialog UI to PDF file in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, itext, jdialog

I want to Convert the Enite Jframe UI to PDF File. I got one Code form here. But It throws Exception says

```
Error in Print Module The document has no pages.
ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPages.writePageTree(PdfPages.java:113)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1221)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:810)
        at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:416)
```

My Code used to Print the JFrame

```
public static void PrintFrameToPDF(JDialog bill)
    {
    try {

            Document d = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(d, new FileOutputStream ("sample.pdf"));
            d.open ();

            PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent( );
            PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(bill.getWidth(),bill.getHeight());
            Graphics2D g2d = template.createGraphics(bill.getWidth(),bill.getHeight());
            bill.print(g2d);
            bill.addNotify();
            bill.validate();


            d.close ();
        }
        catch(Exception e)  {
          System.out.println("Error in Print Module " + e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Usage to Call the PDF 
`PrintModule.PrintFrameToPDF(this);`// This Line PResent in the Current JFrame Form

Comment: What is `bill.getWidth()` & `bill.getHeight()` (the values)?  I bet both are 0.

Comment: just used to get Width and Height for the JFrame set for the PDf size/. Is the exception realted to that size?

Comment: Can you check it and ***answer my question?***  I don't ask questions for the joy of seeing my own typing..

Comment: @Andrew Thompson- you are wrong value is 1063  ,   512

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Factor out the PDF stuff and just paint to an image (e.g. `BufferedImage`) & display it in a `JOptionPane`.  Also, could you decide whether this is dealing with `JFrame` or `JDialog`?  The question seems to flip between the two.

Comment: I want to save as PDF and also I can able to 
Open Pdf using other Java Application... its Dependant on PDf

Comment: "*its Dependant on PDf"*  You job might be, but it is likely that this *question* (or the problem causing it) is not.  I suggest you check you can do the 'pure J2SE' part first, and then when you are sure it is working, proceed to creating the PDF.  Keep trying to do both at once, and you will fail (is my prediction).  In any case, I'll give this problem further thought if you can make a J2SE based SSCCE..